# How can I stop TinyMCE from converting HTML entities back to special characters?

Tags: tinymce, special-characters

When I put something like `&pound;` or `&copy;` into my TinyMCE editor and save the text, then when I load the text back from the database, it appears to turn into the actual £ and © characters. I don't want that. When I check my database, I see that these symbols are stored as `&pound;` and `&copy;`, so it's not a storage problem. Also if I try to store the symbols as `&amp;pound;` and `&amp;copy;`, that doesn't work either, as the character sequences are still converted into original symbols.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I can just htmlspecialchars() the text in my PHP script, and it correctly handles both the formatting and the sequences that are entered. This is rather unexpected, but it actually works out to do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

You may insert a zero-width-no-break-space between `&` and `pound`. This way the editor won't recognise it as an entity/character.

Comment: How is that relevant here?

Comment: not accepting your answer yet... what you said works, but this means that if I want people to be able to write such "&..." sequences, I'll need to do a lot of processing on their text, back and forth. This is probably going to lead to a lot more bugs. Is there a way to disable this replacement behavior altogether?

Comment: no, there is none afaik. Browsers are there to interpret "& and pound" as a character - how could one stop that

Comment: actually, this does not work for me... this tinymce converts ampersands into &amp; and then it converts the whole &amp;pound; thing into just #. Why would it do multiple conversions like that? It should just output what I put in character for character. Isn't there a way to achieve that?

Comment: also with all these conversions, it actually allows to put in <b>text</b> into the form and that's what is saves. I need it to treat that as plain text and not as html. I only need it to use HTML that it itself generates. Isn't there a way to turn off these conversions?